# Why is my WWW-Subdomain not showing?

Tags: ssl, nginx, dns, lets-encrypt, no-www

I am curretly working on a project where WWW subdomain isn't resolving since I moved from my previous server and make my DNS point to the new IP address. Has it something to do with HSTS settings ? SSL certificates ? Wrong redirect format ? Wrong CNAME ?

**On the previous server:**

- I issued a SSL certificate using LetsEncrypt for both domains : website.fr and www.website.fr., running with Debian/Apache
- I terminated the instance without copying the certificate.
- At that time, it worked on both https www and non www

**On the new server:**

- I've created an AWS EC2 under Ubuntu16.04/Nginx
- I've issued a new SSL for both domains using LetsEncrypt
- Sites-available conf file (enabled):

  ```
  server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;
   server_name website.fr www.website.fr;
   return 301 $scheme://website.fr$request_uri;
  }

  server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
   server_name www.website.fr;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.fr/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.fr/privkey.pem;
   include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
   return 301 $scheme://website.fr$request_uri;
  }

  server {
   listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.fr/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.fr/privkey.pem;
   include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
   root /var/www/...
   ...etc...
  ```
- ssl-params.conf

  ```
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECD$
  ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout 5s;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
  add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem; #Diffie-Hellman 2048 group
  ```

**DNS Zone settings:**

IN A XX.XX.XX.XX 
* IN CNAME website.fr.
www IN CNAME website.fr.

Why isn't my WWW-Subdomain also resolving ? Why isn't the page showing ?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved by itself...**

Apparently, nothing was wrong in the configuration. DNS needed A LOT OF TIME to spread (24h+).

Just needed to be patient :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to point another A Record with the host "www" to your IP. 
This needs to be done wherever you bought the domain.

Comment: Thanks @NullDev, I've also tried that yesterday, waited for a few hours but it didn't seem to work.